# What do they say in a linked video? (5 words)

Tags: pronunciation

A video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUVvDM0tIjU

Now parts I'm not getting:

1. 0:21 'till my father was (?). I've been so (?) for quite...'
2. 2:09 '...a shift from (?) enlighting to...'
3. 2:21 '...right on the (?) there.'
4. 2:51 '...connection with the consumers is gonna (?) to the brand.'

If you can help, please, just type a nubmer and a word (words) which corresponds to the number.

Big thanks. Anthony.

**PS**: Not only I wasn't able to get certain words I also messed up words right after/before those. :)

Comment: Over the years the family and the ownership evolved till my father was owner. I've been sole owner for quite a while.

Comment: There's been a shift from incandescent lighting to both energy-saving fluorescent  and LED.

Comment: We want to be right on the front edge of that.

Comment: And the connection with the consumer is gonna be to the brand.  [is going to be]

Answer (score 2):

1. till my father was **owner**. I've been **sole owner** for quite a while.
2. a shift from **incandescent** lighting to ... (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb )
3. We want to be right on the, **right on the front edge of that.** (Speaker is repeating "right on the" twice)
4. connection with the consumers is *gonna **be*** to the brand. (*gonna* = going to)